# how to resolve socket timeout while creating react app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

PS C:\Users\HP\Desktop> npx create-react-app enda_react
Creating a new React app in C:\Users\HP\Desktop\enda_react.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

****npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT**
**npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/bfj failed, reason: Socket timeout****

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-03-10T03_17_13_731Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting enda_react/ from C:\Users\HP\Desktop
Done.

i tried different methods such as
*- increase timeout,
-upadate npm versions,
-unistalled previeous create app and installed new one,
-cleared cache,*

all these methods doesnt worked for me,someone please help

Comment: i resolved this problem by using command : npm config set fetch-retry-maxtimeout 60000 -g, note that : you can increase timeout until problome resolved

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same issue in node V16.14.0, then I've added a timeout flag to solve this issue.

> npx create-react-app clients -timeout=100000

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, then I decided to install react js with this command:

```
 npm init react-app app-name
```

Answer (score 0):

Have been using this for more than two years now:

```
npm config set fetch-retry-maxtimeout 999999999 -g
```

Usually happens when I've got a slow internet connection.

npm install downloads & installs the packages in package.json. I believe this increases the amount of time you have.